# gulp-scss-lint config shows error: bluebird/js/release/promise.js

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

In my code:

```
linter = require('gulp-scss-lint')

const linterOptions = application.config().scss.linting;
linterOptions.config = application.path(linterOptions.config);


return gulp.src(application.path(application.config().scss.source))
        .pipe(linter(linterOptions))
```

So when I use `.pipe(linter(linterOptions))` then, it shows error as below in console.

```
[15:44:08] Starting 'scss'...
(node:24070) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at var/www/html/freewheel_integration/madison-limited/node_modules/gulp-scss-lint/src/index.js:30:18 but was not returned from it
    at new Promise (/var/www/html/freewheel_integration/madison-limited/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
[15:44:09] Finished 'scss' after 471 ms
```

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. Isn't the CSS being generated?

Comment: No, css not generating..